# sending an http request over ssh server

Tags: http, elasticsearch, ssh, server

i have my data residing on an SSH server and i want to inquire and retrieve the data via HTTP POST and GET requests. i have been trying to do that using the simple url's http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search? but it gives me an empty response. What is the correct way to send requests over ssh server through http? my http post function looks something like this:

```
function spatialsearch(coordinates_selected) {
  var coords = coordinates_selected.geometry.coordinates;
  console.log('c',JSON.stringify(coordinates_selected.geometry.coordinates));
  var _url = 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search?';

  var b = {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
          "geo_shape": {
            "metadata.o2r.spatial.geometry": {
              "shape": {
                "type": "polygon",
                "coordinates":
                coords

                /* [
                //     [-22.0, 76.0],
                //     [-27.0, 65.0],
                //     [-57.0, 65.0],
                //     [-59.0, 76.0],
                //     [-22.0, 76.0]
                ]*/

              },
              "relation": "within"
            }}}}}
  };

  console.log(b,'http sending request');
  return $http.post(_url,b);
}
```

i tried SSH tunneling using ssh `-L9201:sshserver:9200 r_chau02@sshserver` but i am still not getting any response.

Comment: Do you have an SSH tunnel to your remote host on which ES runs?

Comment: @Val i am unfamiliar with SSH tunnel as i am new to this thing. i guess i do not have it because the server is just set up using default configurations

Comment: The simply connect to it using `ssh -L9200:a.b.c.d:9200 user@a.b.c.d`and then you'll be able to access your remote ES server on `localhost:9200`

Comment: `ssh -L9200:sshserver:9200 r_chau02@sshserver`

Comment: Please refer to this question for the answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1210021/sending-an-http-request-over-ssh-server/1210032?noredirect=1#comment1765752_1210032

Comment: Basically, the same answer as mine, just that you were mixing up ports :-)

Comment: @Val yes but is there a possibility to do it without tunneling?

Comment: Yes, if you can access `sshserver:9200` directly from your code.

Comment: @Val i tried inserting it into my code but this is the error what i get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Then it either means your server is not accessible from the outside or the port 9200 is firewalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am using SSH tunneling for this purpose using the following statement ssh `L9201:127.0.0.1:9200 r_chau02@sshserver`.